# How to install Sensei theme

Tags: customization

I've only just discovered Blender and after a few hours I can do far more of my simple project than I managed with FreeCAD after hours of struggle.

However I have found the scaling and units a bit confusing and read that Sensei deals with this more simply. I downloaded the zip file and tried running it from the Linux terminal and in the Blender Python console but it errors.

Blender 2.76 on Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.1

Comment: https://blendersensei.com/theme-update/

Comment: when you are confuse with scaling and units why you install sensei addon and why you need theme. And after you download the zip file unzip or extract and then install

Comment: atek: Your first sentence does not make sense - perhaps try Google Translate? Second sentence: I did unzip it, although I didn't say so in my post.

Comment: DFJ: I didn't realise you had posted a message, because it was all in blue I assumed it was just a username associated with Atek's. Now I can see that you are giving me a link. I followed the instructions on the page and it worked. My first attempt hadn't worked because the downloaded file had something wrong with it - the extract resulted in directories and a Python script instead of an XML file

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Duarte Farrahota Ramos for the answer.

Instructions and file to download are here: [Sensei](http://blendersensei.com/theme-update/)

1. Download the file sensei_theme_update_10_21_2013.zip
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Open Blender and go to “File” at the top choose “User Preferences” and then choose the tab “Themes”
4. At the bottom of that screen choose “Install Theme” and select the file you just downloaded on your computer.
5. If you’re happy with the theme changes then go to “File” at the top and select “Save Startup File” and you’re done.

Notes:
(2) Make sure the extract results in an .XML file. 
(5) This doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: The (5) will appear to be necessary if you wish to open Blender with theme already enabled and not re-enable it every time on startup.

Comment: Mr Zak: I think I did "Save User Settings" in the "User Preferences" which may be why (5) didn't appear to be necessary.